# Get list of my own calls through Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft365

I am trying to get a list of my own calls through Microsoft Graph.

In a chat in Microsoft Teams, the calls are listed within the chat, so I thought I might be able to find the records of calls in the list of chat messages. However, they are not there.

I have seen the "Call" API, which looks right at first glance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However, it requires Application permissions and this enables me to get calls from ALL users in the entire tenant, so from a security perspective, it is a whole other ballpark.

So my question is, is there any way I can just get my OWN calls from Microsoft Graph or from any other source in the Microsoft 365 platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to get a list of your own calls through Graph - would you consider [filing a feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) on our M365 dev platform so we can look into this further?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thank you.